# Hoping to verify my solution to $u_{tt}+{2u}_t=u_{xx}$ with below boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I haven't yet succeeded in locating the below type of PDE with a complete answer. I was hoping that my workings out may be verified as correct/complete or incomplete at your convenience.

$$u_{tt}+2{u_t}=u_{xx}$$

with below boundary conditions:

$$u_t(x,0)=0 \text{ for }0<x<1,$$

$$u(x,0)=\text{sin}(\pi x),$$

$$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0 \text{ for } t>0.$$

The solution I derived was $$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_nT_n(t)\text{sin}(\pi n x)$$
where $$T_n(t)=e^{-t}[{\left(\sqrt{1-\pi^2n^2}\right)e^{-t\left(\sqrt{1-\pi^2n^2}\right)}+e^{t\left(\sqrt{1-\pi^2n^2}\right)}}]$$

and
$$A_n=\int_{0}^{1}\text{sin}\left(\pi x\right)\text{sin}\left(\pi n x\right)dx$$

**update**
Courtesy of an update, $$A_n ={1/2}.$$

I look forward to your thoughts and thank you as always for your time.

Comment: If you work through your integral for $A_n$, you’ll find several of them working out to be zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take as our starting point the solution you derived. If we assume that $T_n(0)=1$, the initial condition $u(x,0)=\sin(\pi x)$ implies
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\sin(n\pi x)=\sin(\pi x). \tag{1}
$$
Multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $\sin(m\pi x)\,(m\in \mathbb{N}^*)$, and using the orthogonality relation
$$
\int_0^1\sin(m\pi x)\sin(n\pi x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\delta_{mn}, \tag{2}
$$
we obtain
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\frac{1}{2}\delta_{mn}=\frac{1}{2}\delta_{m1}
\implies A_m=\delta_{m1}
=\begin{cases}
1&\text{if $m=1$,} \\
0&\text{if $m\neq 1$,}
\end{cases} \tag{3}
$$
hence
$$
u(x,t)=T_1(t)\sin(\pi x). \tag{4}
$$
Plugging $(4)$ into the PDE, we verify that $T_1(t)$ must satisfy the ODE
$$
T_1''+2T_1'+\pi^2T_1=0, \tag{5}
$$
which has as general solution
$$
T_1(t)=e^{-t}\left[a\cos(\omega t)+b\sin(\omega t)\right]
\qquad\left(\omega=\sqrt{\pi^2-1}\right). \tag{6}
$$
The coeficients $a$ and $b$ are determined by the conditions $T_1(0)=1$ (see the beginning of this answer) and $T_1'(0)=0$ (which follows from $u_t(x,0)=0$). The final result for $T_1(t)$ is
$$
T_1(t)=e^{-t}\left[\cos(\omega t)+\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega}\right], \tag{7}
$$
with $\omega$ defined in $(6)$.